# break statement must be in loop in apex

Tags: apex

```
String body = '{"attribute1":"value2.","attribute2":"value3.","attribute3":{"value1":{"test1":true},"value2":{"test1":true},"value3":{"test1":true},"value4":{"test1":false,"test5":"xxxx"},"value5":{"test1":false}},"test7":"xxx"}';
Map<String, Object> m = (Map<String, Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(body);
Map<String, Object> dim = (Map<String, Object>) m.get('attribute3');
if(dim.get('value1') != null){
    Map<String, Object> dim1 = (Map<String, Object>) dim.get('value1');
    if(dim1.get('test1') == false){
        //do some logical assignment
        break; - throw error "break statement must be in loop"
    }
}
if(dim.get('value2') != null){
    Map<String, Object> dim1 = (Map<String, Object>) dim.get('value2');
    if(dim1.get('test1') == false){

    }   
}
```

So since I am not using a break statement within loop I assume I got the error. Is there a any way I can use break there?

Comment: What do you expect the break to do? If you want to stop the flow in the method, just use `return`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I want to to stop execution after I reach first false? can I do it using return? Will it stop execution rest?

Comment: Yes, `return` will stop the flow through the method, carrying on from where the method was called.

Comment: Thanks @PhilW. Let me try it and get back.

Comment: Hi @PhilW,it works .Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `break` keyword is for terminating loop iteration, while `return` is for terminating method execution (and, where the method has a non-void return type, specifying the value to be returned to the caller).

Answer (score 0):

What you can do, if you want to jump forward, rather than returning, is to use a do-while loop:

```
do {
  if(whatever()) {
    break;
  }
  moreCodeHere();
} while(false);
evenMoreCodeHere();
```

Because we use the condition `false`, we guarantee that the loop runs exactly once, and control can be directed further into the code.

Of course, if you want the entire function to end, you would use `return`.

This is rather unusual, though, as you'd typically just write:

```
if(!whatever()) {
  moreCodeHere();
}
evenMoreCodeHere();
```